# python elements in file in descending order without the use of built in functions?

Tags: python, max, minimum, built-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting elements from file in descending order without built in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893961/putting-elements-from-file-in-descending-order-without-built-in-functions)

This is what I've written so far:

```
def main():
    try:
        file=open(input("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:" ))
        A =file.read().split()
        n=len(A)
        print ("These following", n,"numbers are in the inputted file:\n", A)
        x=(int, A)

        new_list=[]

        while A:

            minimum=A[0]
            for i in range(n):
                for j in range(n-1):
                    if A[0]<A[1]:
                        minimum=A[0]
                        new_list.append(A[0])


                        print ("Now, lets organize these numbers from highest to lowest:", new_list)


        file.close()   


    except IOError as e:
        print("({})".format(e)


main()
```

This is what I get after running:

```
Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:numbers.txt (<<<file I created)
These following 9 numbers are in the inputted file:
 ['1', '-3', '10', '6', '5', '0', '3', '-5', '20']
```

What I want is that after I output the numbers in the file, to organize them in descending order. I've been at this for days. I understand the concept to return the lowest to the back of the line. But how do I go about this? I am very stuck.

Comment: Could you please fix the code formatting at the top of your question?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question a day or so ago? (With broken formatting as well.)

Comment: What is wrong with your solution to this problem in your other question?

Comment: More to the point: why are you avoiding built-in functions if your programming education doesn't even involve sorting algorithms?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, the map function caused a lot of errors. I apologize, I'm new to the website. I didn't know if I should ask again or make a comment in my previous question. Didn't think anyone will see it.

Comment: Also: avoid nesting loops and `if`s four levels deep. Your code would be much clearer if you used helper functions like `find_minimum()` etc.

Comment: Well I was instructed to use algorithms and no built in functions to do the sorting.

Comment: @user1906407 It depends. You should ask a comment if you want clarification on an existing answer. You should ask a new question if it's substantially different from your previous one. That said, your new question should include more attempts at diagnosis than copy-pasted program output. Did you try a debugger? Or sprinkling `print` statements to see where the program gets and where it doesn't?

Comment: @user1906407 Then decompose your program into multiple parts. Do you have a problem with the general flow of your program? Then your sorting algorithm isn't really important. Or is your sorting algorithm implementation broken? (Test that, and only that! Using some hardcoded data, without the IO clutter.) If so, ask only about the sorting algorithm. Don't dump your whole program on SO, saying "something somewhere isn't working right".

Comment: Stray observations: 1. you're never removing elements from `A`, so `while A` will run forever. You're never appending `minimum` to `new_list`. You also have `if A[0] < A[1]:` which will either always be true or never be true because you're never modifying `A` at all. Then you have a boundary condition where even if you were removing items from `A`, that condition would fail when there's only one element in `A` left. You're also iterating over `0..n`, despite the fact that (were you to empty `A`) the length of `A` would have changed.

Comment: So, somehow, you managed to post a program that's MORE glaringly broken than in your previous question. Also, don't enumerate over index ranges. That's almost never useful in Python. Enumerate over list slices, e.g. `for x in A[1:]` to look at every element in A after the first. Also, don't use `A` as a variable name ever. `Python` also already has a `min()` function so you don't need to find the minimum yourself. (Depending on whether or not it counts as "built-in" function for the purpose of your assignment. It's not a sorting function, and you can't write Python without *any* builtins.)

Comment: I did play around with the print statements. When aligned with for j I get endless amounts of empty brackets. I also attempting to give a different array for each iteration. So after minimum=A[0], I did minimum=A[1] and the result will give me 10. The numbers in the file are 1 -3 10 6 5 0 3 -5 20. So I feel that I might be on the right track but I'm not implementing it in the right way.